# Order of evaluation of conditionals in actionscript 3.0 (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, conditional-statements

```
var btn:Button;
if(btn != null  &&  btn.label != '') {
      mx.controls.Alert.show("d");  
}
```

In the above if clause, is it guaranteed that the first condition(btn != null) will
be evaluated before the second condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - ActionScript performs appropriate short-circuiting for the `&&` operator:

- http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary013.html

So not only will it evaluate the expressions in the order you described, it won't bother evaluating the second expression at all if the first one returns `false` (which is as important a detail as the order of evaluation).

Just as a note, ActionScript also supports [short-circuiting the logical or operator (`||`)](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary031.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. Excerpts from the [Adobe livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/operators.html#logical_AND) regarding `&&` operator:

> `&&` **logical `AND` Operator**:
>
> Usage:
>
> `expression1 && expression2`
>
> Returns `expression1` if it is `false` or can be converted to `false`, and `expression2` otherwise.